# run as .jar results in a different view

Tags: java, charts, jar, stacked-area-chart

I write a programm which shows a waveform by using an Areachart.When i compile it and run it it looks just fine like below.When i execute the .jar file i get a complete different view of my waveform.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.AreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class AreaChartSample extends Application {

private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 500;

private Series series;
private int xSeriesData = 0;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private ExecutorService executor;
private AddToQueue addToQueue;
private Timeline timeline2;
private NumberAxis xAxis;

private int time_counter=0;
private int [] data_array=null;

private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

    String line,full_text="";

    try {
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/testvideo/test.txt")); 

       while((line=in.readLine())!= null)
       {
           full_text+=line;
       }

       data_array=new int[full_text.length()];
        for(int i=0;i<full_text.length();i++)
        {
            data_array[i]=((int)(full_text.charAt(i)))-127;
           // data_array[i]=((int)(full_text.charAt(i)))-300;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }



    xAxis = new NumberAxis(0,MAX_DATA_POINTS,MAX_DATA_POINTS/10);
    xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-127,127,1);

    yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);

    //-- Chart
    final AreaChart<Number, Number> sc = new AreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
        // Override to remove symbols on each data point
        @Override protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item) {}
    };
    sc.setAnimated(false);
    sc.setId("liveAreaChart");
    sc.setTitle("Animated Area Chart");

    //-- Chart Series
    series = new AreaChart.Series<Number, Number>();
    series.setName("Area Chart Series");
    sc.getData().add(series);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(sc));
}

@Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    init(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.show();

    //-- Prepare Executor Services
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
    executor.execute(addToQueue);
    //-- Prepare Timeline
    prepareTimeline();

     primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
       executor.shutdown();
    });


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private class AddToQueue implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // add a item of random data to queue
            dataQ.add(data_array[time_counter]);
            time_counter+=100;
            Thread.sleep(10);
            executor.execute(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AreaChartSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}

//-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
private void prepareTimeline() {
    // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override public void handle(long now) {
            addDataToSeries();
        }
    }.start();
}

private void addDataToSeries() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
        if (dataQ.isEmpty()) break;
        Number y=dataQ.remove();
        series.getData().add(new AreaChart.Data(xSeriesData++, y));
       // System.out.println(y);
    }
    // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
    if (series.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
        series.getData().remove(0, series.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
    }
    // update 
      xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData-MAX_DATA_POINTS);
      xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData-1);
}
```

}

when i just run it =>

[image]

when i execute the build .jar file (windows 7 64 bit -> java8)

[image]

I have absolute no idea why this can happen.

Update: here is test.txt: http://expirebox.com/download/bf9be466e23c4c3d8f73f094f261dfbe.html

**UPDATE2**

Okay it must have to do with the reading of the file.when i change

```
 data_array[i]=((int)(full_text.charAt(i)))-127;
```

to

```
  data_array[i]=data_array[i]=((int)('f'))-127;
```

it is the same in both "versions".

Is there are another method which could read correct in both ways.Maybe it has to do with UTF8 or so?

Comment: What is the content of file `C:/testvideo/test.txt`?

Comment: Does the reader read the exact same String values in both cases ?

Comment: Yes, it use the same file. The content of test.txt is just chars like "yq~{z~{{~t{zs{~x{{z}w~{~x{...."

Comment: If you want somebody investigates the problem you have to publish workable and reproduceable sample of this file

Comment: Sorry, i added it at the end.

Comment: And what do you mean by "*when i just run it*"? I've tested it in Intellij IDEA - all works fine

Comment: "when i just run it" means that i "run file" in netbeans. When i start the .jar file by double clicking i get the second image.

Comment: Different version of jar, something else, net beans bug, etc. Recompile/rebuild/restart. This can not be reproduced

Comment: i figured out that it has to do with the file reading(added to the end of my post). Is there are another method which could read correct in both ways.Maybe it has to do with UTF8 or so?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick. Thank you!

```
String fileName = "C:/testvideo/test.txt";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
```